# FlowType : return type of function (k) => obj[k]

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I have a `User` object:

```
type User = {
  name: string,
};
```

That has a `get()` function, that takes in parameter the key of an attribute on `User` and returns this attribute.
The function get is

```
User.prototype.get = (prop) => {
  return this[prop];
};
```

How can I write this fonction definition ?
Here's what I got so far:

```
type User = {
  name: string,
  get: (k: $Keys<User>) => any, // How can I change any to the correct property type ?
};
```

Comment: What is the expected type? `string`? If you were to add an `age: number` property to `User`, would it be `string | number`?

Comment: Yes exactly. But the return type should be the the return type of `obj[prop]` so we can typecheck more precisely

Comment: The expected type is 'string' if it is called with 'name' and 'number' if it is called with 'age'. I don't know if this kind of dynamic typing is possible right now with Flow

Comment: Not sure about Flow but in TypeScript you'd write `get<T extends keyof User>(key: T): User[T]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you can use now `$ElementType<T, K>`.
To be confirmed !

Source: https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/4122#issuecomment-314700605

---

**EDIT:** [Working example](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgCqAzngE5gC8YA3qmGAHYCGAtngFxjEZkCWjAOYAaemGaDOTAK6sARuVEBfdAGM4jHmGmkyXEuSq0xLdlwDkASRhY8xc6IYSpAJgCMy9FGmNVGPhpgkhgAPADSXDz8QgB8ABQA1nhYXGEAlFwAJACiMHjsjBgAKrh4IQZkwmBhMcYMZHgY0mSM2roA2klYALoA3KgqqOqaGDLy5FyMsgoU1MFx5qZ45mm9YMDAYORkcGRDGlpT42Quk9OGc40LzitrG2AIuwnE+yPcvAKCkR9CRvOLbGWq3Wm0eZGery0UU+p3e0UEfyu5huwPu212qCAA)

```
/* @flow */

type User = {
  name: string,
  age: number,
}

const user: User = {
  name: 'Ilyes',
  age: 21,
}

function get<K: string>(key: K): $ElementType<User, K> {
  return user[key];
}

const number: number = get('name'); // error
const number2: number = get('age'); // works
const string: string = get('name'); // works
const string2: string = get('age'); // error
```